# Applying window's heigth to margin-bottom property

Tags: javascript, html, css, window, height

I have the following code:

html:

```
<div id="footer-container">
    last line in page
</div>
```

css:

```
#footer-container {
    margin-bottom:800px; // needs improvement
}
```

The idea is to allow users see the background image completely. It works. But `800px` can be shorter or longer depending of user's window's dimensions.

Is it possible gives to `margin-bottom` the window's current height value, without javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  JavaScript is the only way to access the rendered dimensions of an element.  However, background images can be scaled in modern browsers:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size

Comment: Thanks @cimmanon but my question is not about background-images. I think that your first attempt _No. JavaScript is the only way to access the rendered dimensions of an element._ it should be the correct answer. I'll check it and come back to you, thanks.-

Comment: Refusing to accept the given answer as is seems petty, since you do not indicate that you are willing to use JS to achieve the desired effect.  That iss why I offered a potential pure CSS solution.

Comment: You don't understood me. I said that your answer seems the correct one. I just want to be sure before check it. And yes, I asked for a CSS solution. As I said I'll back to you when be sure about this. Thanks...